# Web API to push notification on Xamarin - what is the flow?

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I am trying to understand how a typical web API would send notifications to a native app. After reading some more I got even more confused, since there are lots of tools managing parts of the notifications.

As I understand it the default flow would be:

1. Some action happens in web API and we need to make a push notifications
2. We find out which user that needs to receive this push notification
3. Using a tool such as Azure Notification Hubs to send the notification
4. Somehow integrate the Azure Notification Hub inside the Xamarin solution

This just leaves a couple of questions.

First of all: How do I map a user to a specific app? Second of all, what tool do you use on the app site? I guess the app need to "register" somehow?

I hope someone can shed some light on this proces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/user-notifications/deprecated/remote_notifications_in_ios/) talking about the push notification topology for iOS as follows:

> At the center of push notifications in iOS is the Apple Push Notification Gateway Service (APNS). This is a service provided by Apple that is responsible for routing notifications from an application server to iOS devices.

[image]

Before an iOS application can receive remote notification, You need to register your iOS application with APNS. And APNS will return a device token to your iOS application, then you need to register the device token to your application server or Azure Notification hubs for registration. Then the application server or Azure Notification hubs would push notifications to the specific mobile device with the device token. For more details, you could refer to the **Registering with APNS** section from the above tutorial. The following diagram illustrates the process of registration and obtaining a device token:

[image]

> How do I map a user to a specific app?

After registered with APNS, you could register the device token along with the tags that could identify a specific user to your application server or Azure Notification Hubs. Here is a diagram illustrates the above scenario for Notification Hubs, you could refer to it:

[image]

> what tool do you use on the app site?

I would prefer to use Microsoft Azure Notification Hubs, you could use the related SDK for pushing notifications to all clients or clients with specific tags. For more details, you could refer to [Sending Push Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#sending-push-notifications).

Additionally, for connecting your Xamarin app to the notification hub, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#connect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub). For a detailed steps about iOS Push Notifications with Notification Hubs for Xamarin apps, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started).